# Eliminar signos de una cadena excluyendo los guiones, Python

Tags: python, regex

Buen dia, Tengo un problema con este codigo. No encuentro la forma de poder excluir los `-` para que no se eliminen.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import re
import unicodedata
import ast
def remove_accents(input_str): #con esta funcion elimino las tildes
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    return u"".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])

test = "¿Hola?, ☆ Soy ☆ ùn - ejèmplo!!!"
print(re.sub(r'[^\d.a-zA-Z ]','',re.sub(",", "", remove_accents(test))))
```

Y eso me duvuelve

```
Hola Soy un  ejemplo
```

Yo busco que no me elimine el `-`, Osea que me devuelve de esta forma

```
Hola Soy un - ejemplo
```

Si dé repente hay otra forma de eliminar los signos sin tener que eliminar los `-`, Lo agradecería!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un pequeño detallito: debes agregar un guión después de la *Z* en la expresión, para que así esté en el listado de caracteres que *no* se modifican:

```
print(re.sub(r'[^\d.a-zA-Z- ]','',re.sub(",", "", remove_accents(test))))
```

Ejemplo:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d.a-zA-Z- ]','', "hola-adios☆12?3~")
'hola-adios123'
```